# Enumerators and Thread-safety

Tags: .net, linq, thread-safety, ienumerable

Just to make sure, say that i have this code:

```
this.allObjects =  [some linq query];
```

and have two methods that both read (not modify) this IEnumerable, are they safe to call in parallel? Just looping through a IEnumerable should be safe right?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the implementation of the Enumerator, but in most cases, yes, it is safe.

One note though: the pseudocode, as you have it, doesn't actually do anything (due to deferred execution).  The LINQ query will only execute when you access `allObjects` (or if you call something like `ToList()` on the LINQ query).

Comment: Yes, but that's good right? When  I access the linq query by for-eaching over it for instance it will run GetEnumerator and generate a new IEnumerable...  looping over the same IEunumerable might be worse..

Comment: Correct.  The only time concurrency is an issue is if iterating through makes modifications (which is not what anyone would expect, but is possible) -- however this never happens with standard collections.

Answer (score 0):

The `IEnumerable<T>` instances are probably fine (although it does depend on implementation).

`IEnumerator<T>` instances are probably **not** fine (although again: implementation details).